# reduce and optimize a function with javascript language

Tags: javascript, optimization, reduce, simplify

Good morning, I have the following code with the programming language javascript.
And the thing is, I've been asked to optimize the function.
Reduce the lines of code, that is, simplify it.
Any suggestion?
Thanks

```
function translate(box){
    var row = box.substring(1,3);
    var column = box.substring(0,1);
    switch(column){
        case "a":
            return "1"+row;
        case "b":
            return "2"+row;
        case "c":
            return "3"+row;
        case "d":
            return "4"+row;
        case "e":
            return "5"+row;
        case "f":
            return "6"+row;
        case "g":
            return "7"+row;
        case "h":
            return "8"+row;
    }
    registraMoviment(box);
}
```

So far I haven't tried anything because I don't work with javascript or related languages, but I've been given this assignment anyway. Thank you

Comment: Replace switch with map of _string to number_ (`{a: 1, b: 2}` and then do `lettersMap[column] + row`

Comment: Please don't vandalize your question. You can flag it for deletion by a moderator.

Comment: Since the question doesn't contain any info that must be purged from the history. You could just press the *delete* button below the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```js
const input = 'bRow';

function translate(box){
    var row = box.substring(1,3);
    var column = box.substring(0,1);
    
    return (column.charCodeAt(0) - 96) + row;
}

console.log(translate(input));
```

For more info please read:

- [ASCII table](https://www.asciitable.com/)
- [String.prototype.charCodeAt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt)

P.S. I didn't clearly understand the logic of `registraMoviment(box);` so I didn't include it in my example

Comment: @elzizi23 I was glad!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function translate(box){
  var row = box.substring(1,3);
  var column = box.substring(0,1);
  var obj = {"a":"1", "b":"2", "c":"3", "d":"4", "e":"5", "f":"6", "g":"7", "h":"8" }
  for(item in obj){
    if(column === item){
      return obj[item] + row
    }
  }
    registraMoviment(box);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ASCII values of your letters to do this more mathy, but it certainly is much less readable.

```js
function translate(box){
    const row = box.substring(1,3);
    const column = box.substring(0,1);
    if(column >= "a" && column <= "h") {
      const ASCII_VALUE_a = 97
      // The +1 is to make it 1-indexed. The -ASCII_VALUE_a is to shift it so that "a" then becomes 1. 
      return `${column.charCodeAt() + 1 - ASCII_VALUE_a}${row}`
    }
    registraMoviment(box);
}

const box = "b13" // expected to become "213"
console.log(translate(box)) // 213
```

Another solution is Justinas' comment:

```js
function translate(box){
    const row = box.substring(1,3);
    const column = box.substring(0,1);
    const lookup = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4, e: 5, f: 6: g: 7, h: 8 }
    if(column in lookup) {
      return lookup[column] + row
    }
    registraMoviment(box);
}

const box = "b13" // expected to become "213"
console.log(translate(box)) // 213
```